# Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Program failed to complete

Tags: anchor-lang, anchor-client, anchor-test

I get this error when I am calling an instruction of a program from a client. I am using Seahorse library to write smart contract. The library transpiles python code to anchor rust program.

Here's the client code:

```
    it("add liquidity", async () => {
        const tokenAmountA = 400_000_000;
        const tokenAmountB = 400_000_000;

        const tx = await program.methods
            .addLiquidity(new anchor.BN(tokenAmountA), new anchor.BN(tokenAmountB))
            .accounts({
                user: userPk,
                pool: poolPk,
                tokenMintA: tokenMintAPk,
                tokenMintB: tokenMintBPk,
                userTokenAccountA: userTokenAccountAPk,
                userTokenAccountB: userTokenAccountBPk,
                poolTokenVaultA: poolTokenVaultAPk,
                poolTokenVaultB: poolTokenVaultBPk,
                lpTokenMint: lpTokenMintPk,
                userLpTokenAccount: userLPTokenAccountPk,
            })
            .signers([user])
            .rpc();

        console.log("Your transaction signature", tx);
    });
```

Here's the instruction code in transpiled rust language:

```
    #[derive(Accounts)]
    # [instruction (token_amount_a : u64 , token_amount_b : u64)]
    pub struct AddLiquidity<'info> {
        #[account(mut)]
        pub user: Signer<'info>,
        #[account(mut)]
        pub pool: Box<Account<'info, dot::program::Pool>>,
        #[account(mut)]
        pub token_mint_a: Box<Account<'info, Mint>>,
        #[account(mut)]
        pub token_mint_b: Box<Account<'info, Mint>>,
        #[account(mut)]
        pub user_token_account_a: Box<Account<'info, TokenAccount>>,
        #[account(mut)]
        pub user_token_account_b: Box<Account<'info, TokenAccount>>,
        #[account(mut)]
        pub pool_token_vault_a: Box<Account<'info, TokenAccount>>,
        #[account(mut)]
        pub pool_token_vault_b: Box<Account<'info, TokenAccount>>,
        #[account(mut)]
        pub lp_token_mint: Box<Account<'info, Mint>>,
        # [account (init , payer = user , seeds = ["lp-token-account" . as_bytes () . as_ref () , lp_token_mint . key () . as_ref () , user . key () . as_ref ()] , bump , token :: mint = lp_token_mint , token :: authority = user)]
        pub user_lp_token_account: Box<Account<'info, TokenAccount>>,
        pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
        pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
        pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    }
```

```
    pub fn add_liquidity(
        ctx: Context<AddLiquidity>,
        token_amount_a: u64,
        token_amount_b: u64,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        let mut programs = HashMap::new();

        programs.insert(
            "system_program",
            ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
        );

        programs.insert(
            "token_program",
            ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
        );

        let programs_map = ProgramsMap(programs);
        let user = SeahorseSigner {
            account: &ctx.accounts.user,
            programs: &programs_map,
        };

        let pool = dot::program::Pool::load(&mut ctx.accounts.pool, &programs_map);
        let token_mint_a = SeahorseAccount {
            account: &ctx.accounts.token_mint_a,
            programs: &programs_map,
        };

        let token_mint_b = SeahorseAccount {
            account: &ctx.accounts.token_mint_b,
            programs: &programs_map,
        };

        let user_token_account_a = SeahorseAccount {
            account: &ctx.accounts.user_token_account_a,
            programs: &programs_map,
        };

        let user_token_account_b = SeahorseAccount {
            account: &ctx.accounts.user_token_account_b,
            programs: &programs_map,
        };

        let pool_token_vault_a = SeahorseAccount {
            account: &ctx.accounts.pool_token_vault_a,
            programs: &programs_map,
        };

        let pool_token_vault_b = SeahorseAccount {
            account: &ctx.accounts.pool_token_vault_b,
            programs: &programs_map,
        };

        let lp_token_mint = SeahorseAccount {
            account: &ctx.accounts.lp_token_mint,
            programs: &programs_map,
        };

        let user_lp_token_account = Empty {
            account: SeahorseAccount {
                account: &ctx.accounts.user_lp_token_account,
                programs: &programs_map,
            },
            bump: ctx.bumps.get("user_lp_token_account").map(|bump| *bump),
        };

        add_liquidity_handler(
            user.clone(),
            pool.clone(),
            token_mint_a.clone(),
            token_mint_b.clone(),
            user_token_account_a.clone(),
            user_token_account_b.clone(),
            pool_token_vault_a.clone(),
            pool_token_vault_b.clone(),
            lp_token_mint.clone(),
            user_lp_token_account.clone(),
            token_amount_a,
            token_amount_b,
        );

        dot::program::Pool::store(pool);

        return Ok(());
    }
```

I have passed the required parameters and account to the instructions. I don't understand why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 4):

Can you do

```
 }).rpc({
  skipPreflight:true
})
```

This will not simulate the tx and you could get better errors

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the suggestion to enable this feature. Using it, I was able to pinpoint the error in the program.